# How to invoke CLI and respond to prompts from Node.js

Tags: node.js, prompt

I am writting a node.js program that invokes openssl on linux.

```
var cmd = 'openssl req -new -sha256 -key delegation.key -out delegation.csr';
```

This sets off a series of prompts for user input:

```
Country Name (2 letter code) [AU]:
State or Province Name (full name) [Some-State]:
Locality Name (eg, city) []:
Organization Name (eg, company) [Internet Widgits Pty Ltd]:
Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []:
Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name) []:
Email Address []:

Please enter the following 'extra' attributes
to be sent with your certificate request
A challenge password []:
An optional company name []:
```

I would like my node.js program to automatically fill in the answers and hit the 'enter' key for each.

tx!

Answer (score 1):

Use **child_process**

```
var childprocess = require('child_process');
var openssl = childprocess.spawn('openssl', ['req','-new','-sha256','-key','delegation.key','-out','delegation.csr']);
openssl.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');

var current = '';
openssl.stdout.on("data", function(data) {
    current += data;
    if (current[current.length-1] == '\n') {

        // Handle text in "current" (this is what openssl has written)

        // if we should reply {

            var reply = 'MY REPLY TO WHAT IS IN CURRENT';

            childProcess.stdin.write(reply + '\n');

        // } else {
            // (if we are finished - have no more replies)
            // openssl.stdin.end();
        // }
        current = '';
    }
});
```